# Getting access to Boost Test classes - test_results and results_collector

Tags: c++, boost-test

I've been able to configure Boost Test to create a report when the tests are complete but what I'd also like to do is while running a set of tests to be able to print the pass/fail state of each test to the console as the tests are running.

So I started looking into how I might get access to the test_results and results_collector classes in Boost Test. But I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the test executable with the `--log_level=all` flag it will print whether the checks failed or passed.

For more info on boost test runtime parameters check [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm already aware of that. I want to choose how to output the pass/fail details myself by using the test_results class (for example) but I can't figure out how to get a handle to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up your own [log formatter](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost/unit_test/unit_test_log_formatter.html) and register it like [this](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/test_output/logging_api/custom_log_formatter.html).

The API has slightly changed in 1.62 but stays backward compatible. Your log formatter can manage its own `log_level`. Have a look at the boost.test log formatter existing implementations: some sequences can be a bit tricky.